# Visual Studio Code . folder with files after some time deleted

Tags: visual-studio-code

i am a new user of  Visual Studio Code. The problem is when i create a folder for files, it deletes after awhile and i have to begin from null again. I've faced with this probles 2 times. How can i fix this? what's the problem?
thank you all for helping to noob.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start working with a source control tool to help you keep track on your projects.

Try using `git` which is the most popular one now days and use an external git client such as Sourcetree (you can also use the visual studio code git tool but my opinion is to use an external one which is more cleaner and easier to understand visually)

Read more about **Git** - https://git-scm.com/

Read more about **Sourcetree** - https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/